# How to run app that work in tablets to smartphone?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am very very new to Android and  I was assigned  a project of a system that is working on tablet and the idea is that it also works in smartphone. From what I could see, it was developed with the API 13, and I would take it to the API 19, but is giving me some errors:

```
C:\Projects\TestAndroid\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(206) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(208) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(216) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(223) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.

C:\Projects\TestAndroid\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(82, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(82, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(82, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(82, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
```

Does anyone know of any material in which to handle this issue? From already thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `\res\values-v21\` folder. You won't need it when your target API Level is 19. (Material Design Theme needs API Level 21)

Comment: Hi Michael, I still have the issue.

Comment: You need to "Rebuild" the project. (Menu: Build > Rebuild)